# PHP JOIN always return null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm barely new using DB hosted on a real server, I have a SELECT:

```
SELECT P.IdPromocion, P.TipoPromocion, P.Habilitada, P.Cantidad, P.Monto, P.Descuento, P.ProductoCompra, P.ProductoBeneficio, N1.Nombre AS NombreCompra, N2.Nombre AS NombreBeneficio 
FROM promociones AS P 
JOIN productos AS N1 ON P.ProductoCompra = N1.Modelo 
JOIN productos AS N2 ON P.ProductoBeneficio = N2.Modelo
```

And when i run it on phpMyAdmin from the server it returns the results to be expected, but in the PHP CombreCompra and NombreBeneficio are always null.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host','user','password','DB');
    $Array = array();
    $query = "SELECT P.IdPromocion, P.TipoPromocion, P.Habilitada, P.Cantidad, P.Monto, P.Descuento, P.ProductoCompra, P.ProductoBeneficio, N1.Nombre AS NombreCompra, N2.Nombre AS NombreBeneficio FROM promociones AS P JOIN productos AS N1 ON P.ProductoCompra = N1.Modelo JOIN productos AS N2 ON P.ProductoBeneficio = N2.Modelo";
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );
    $mysqli->close();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
        $Array [] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($Array);
    exit;
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're closing your DB connection `$mysqli->close();` before your `while` loop. Put it after `exit;`

Comment: Try not to close the connection before `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Same, both columns NombreCompra and NombreBeneficio are always null

Comment: Try and pass something into `$row` like a column name. `$row` by itself may not yield any results.

Comment: I do get results, I get all the data from the table 'promociones' but the data from the table 'productos' are always null

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code !?! :-(

Comment: It's just not possible - can we see proper DDLs

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's a DDLs

Comment: Are you sure the query in PHP and the query in PhpMyAdmin are run both on the same database? Maybe PhpMyAdmin is being run on a remote web server and the Php is run locally ? In that case, do both machines contain the same data?

Comment: I upload the database on 000webhost.com, it have it's own phpMyAdmin where I execute the Query, also the php is uploaded in the same server and with the 000webhost mysql data

Comment: ok, try changing `$result = $mysqli->query( $query );` into `$result = $mysqli->query( $query ) or die ($mysqli->error());` and tell us if you are getting an error.

Comment: Same, no error, NombreBeneficio and NombreProducto still null